# Background images rounded cornes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make rounded cornes on this background images. But it seems to effect the div box instead.

```
<div class="watermark">
<div class="watermark-image" style="background-image:url({{blogthreadlist.blogUri}});"></div>
<div class="col-md-12">Something else</div>
<div class="col-md-12">Something more..</div>
<div class="col-md-12">Something at the end</div>
```

```
.watermark {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.watermark-image {
  content: "";
  opacity: 0.2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;   
}
```

How do I round the cornes of the images and not the div box? The div i larger than the picture..

Comment: you can't give rounded corners for the background images.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a separate `<img>` tag for the image and set a `border-radius`

```
<div class="watermark-image"><img class="rounded-img" src="{{blogthreadlist.blogUri}}"></img></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.rounded-img {
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rounded Corner for image, try this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/sdpuaz11/)

```
<div class="watermark-image" style="background-image:url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQNbB93-oZdCcp-OwO5m05v07sAJe42lOpOy8dRnT3aZ8uArqZJ);background-repeat: repeat-x;border-radius: 5px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 .watermark-image {
  content: "";
  opacity: 0.2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;   
  border-radius:50px;
}
```